# Is it a good practice Theme based on extension?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating my theme based on extending ThemeData, the main reason is that I have access to `brightness` where I can get if my actual theme is `dark or light`.

Is this a good practice? May I have any drawbacks or performance issues?

```
extension MyAppBarTheme on ThemeData {
  TextStyle get myBarTitleStyle {}
}

extension MyFlatButtonIconTheme on ThemeData {
  TextStyle get myFlatButtonStyle {}
}
```